# Determining which part of the conditional is true in an `if` statement

Tags: php, if-statement

Suppose I have an `if` statement in PHP, like this:

```
if($var || $var2 || $var3){
  //code
}
```

How do I know which variable triggered the `if` statement?

Comment: Pls read https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp to understand how conditional statements work.

Comment: By checking inside your code if you enter that IF block. But PHP won't tell you this information otherwise.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan if it was obvious that it was the one that was truthy, Badr wouldn't have asked the question. Do you have a suggestion for another way to code this other than a switch statement or by using if / elseif ?

Comment: @YvonneAburrow 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

If you must know, you need a conditional on each one.

```
if ($var1) {
  // Do someting
} elseif ($var2) {
  // Do something else
} // etc...
```

Alternatively, if you have several conditions you want to check in this manner, you can hijack a [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) for this purpose:

```
switch(true) {
  case $var1:
    // Do something
    break;
  case $var2:
    // Do something else
    break;
  // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible only if you change a little your way to think

```
$data=7;$data2=false;$data3='';
if($filter=array_filter(compact('data','data2','data3'))){
    echo key($filter);//output data
}
```

A little explanation :

first we compact all variables in one array with the `compact` function
second we filter the array with the `array_filter` function 
At this step all is done.if `$filter` is `empty` the `if` condition will be evaluated to false and if `$filter` is not `empty` it means that at least one of the variable is different of `false or null or empty string` 
Then to know  the one of  this variable which triggered the if you can check the $filter array specially the first element.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a switch statement instead of an if statement.

```
switch ($var) {
case "content of var1":
    code to be executed if $var = "content of var1";
    break;
case "content of var2":
    code to be executed if $var = "content of var2";
    break;
case "content of var3":
    code to be executed if $var = "content of var3";
    break;
...
default:
    code to be executed if $var is something else;
}
```

Note that everything inside the quotes "" is a string and therefore should be whatever your $var1, $var2, or $var3 are likely to contain.

Also note that in this example, there is only one $var and it stores different content depending on the situation.